# how vlook up works when we have duplicates in first column of table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

there are 2 different files i wanted to check based on vehicle_ID(look up value), is there any color change between two files. but here there duplicated in vehicle ID column so i am not getting exact value

```
VIN                  MAPPED_COLOR

VF12R071659666728   Cappuccino Noir Etoilé       
VF12R071659666728   Gris Cassiopée Noir Étoil
VF12R071659666730   Gris Platine Noir Etoilé
VF12R071659666731   Noir Etoilé Ivoire
VF12R071659666752   Rouge Flamme Noir Etoilé
```

---

```
=VLOOKUP($C$2:$C$25576,'[IZMOVN - COLOR MATCHING REPORT_3rd_July_2019_1.xlsx]IZMOVN - COLOR MATCHING REPORT'!$A:$Z,15,0)
```

---

```
VIN                     MAPPED_COLOR            V_loop_up_MAPPED_COLOR

VF12R071659666728   Cappuccino Noir Etoilé      Cappuccino Noir Etoilé  
VF12R071659666728   Gris Cassiopée Noir Étoil   Cappuccino Noir Etoilé  
VF12R071659666730   Gris Platine Noir Etoilé    Gris Platine Noir Etoilé    
VF12R071659666731   Noir Etoilé Ivoire          Noir Etoilé Ivoire  TRUE
VF12R071659666752   Rouge Flamme Noir Etoilé    Rouge Flamme Noir Etoilé
```

Comment: this is just sample , there are totally 25000 records are there in both files , when same vehicle ID has two different colors i wanted to pick first occurrence of duplicate should pick first mapped color  and for second occurrence should pick second mapped colors , any suggestions?

Comment: Do a countif() of the target vin then do 1 or 2 vlookups depending on result. But why would a vin have two colors against it? like having 2 radios...

Comment: like one vehicle model can have different colors in market and how 2 vlookups will work when one not satisfying could please explain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean a vin is not model specific, it is an **individual** vehicle identifier, and **if** you have the codes of all the parts of the vin you can get the paint code from the vin and therefore the precise color the vehicle left the factory with.

Comment: Actually if there are duplicates in your list there **is** no exact value that a lookup could return. You need to think of another approach like filtering …

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I don’t get why there are duplicates though vins are vehicle specific not model....

Comment: @SolarMike While you are correct, that doesn't mean that duplicates are not possible. They might be the result of consolidated data of 2 different sources (we don't know where the data actually comes from). • Nevertheless the question is to broad to answer.

Comment: @SolarMike VIN can be duplicate because data is from many sources combined. same vehicle can have another dealer also. and as i already mentioned this is only sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data sheet `data1` looks like below, add a helper column before the `MAPPED_COLOR` column like in the image (1) below using the formula

```
=A2 & "-" & COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

to append the number of occurence `-1`, `-2` at the VIN to make them unique for your lookup.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Sheet "Data1"</sup>*

Then in your other sheet add columns `1` to `4` or more. Note that the names must be the numbers (nothing else!). Then use the following forumla in B2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Data1!$A:$A,$A2)>=B$1,VLOOKUP($A2 & "-" & B$1,Data1!$B:$C,2,FALSE),"")
```

and copy it right and down to get the result below:

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: Sheet "Data2"</sup>*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will only ever have two matches for a VIN number (from two data sources) you can use this formula to find the second match: `=INDEX(B1:B6,SMALL(IF(A1:A6=D2,ROW(A1:A6)-MIN(ROW(A1:A6))+1),2))`

*(Note this is an array formula, and needs to be closed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+,<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)*

The formulas I've used in the screenshot below:

**E2:**`=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(D2,A1:A6,0))`

**F2:**`=INDEX(B1:B6,SMALL(IF(A1:A6=D2,ROW(A1:A6)-MIN(ROW(A1:A6))+1),2))` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+,<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

**G2:**`=IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,D2)>1,INDEX($B$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7=$D2,ROW($A$1:$A$7)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$7))+1),2))=INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MATCH($D2,$A$1:$A$7,0)),TRUE)` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+,<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: is there any another way? i want first occurrence and second occurrence in same column.

Comment: There are definitely other ways. If this formula is too difficult for you to understand, I would recommend steering clear of attempting to brute force the problem with a formula. You will save much more time by adding a second column that classifies the VIN and colour by coming from data source 1 or 2, then you can look up the second match separately. Better yet, don't combine the datasets in the one sheet to begin with and then you can tell the difference between the two.

Comment: suppose if i found duplicates can i make those as unique value something like this ?(For first duplicate occurrence should add '-1',second duplicate occurence '-2')

  VF12R071659666728-1
  VF12R071659666728-2
  VF12R071659666730
  VF12R071659666731